# Why use 非 and 亚 for continent names?

Tags: meaning, place-names, proper-nouns

Why was 非 chosen for 非洲 (Africa) and 亚 chosen for 亚洲 (Asia)?

I can't find a particular reason to use these characters.

Comment: +1: I have wondered the same thing. Surely they could have used similar-sounding characters with more auspicious meanings.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

亚洲 is short for 亚细亚洲 while 非洲 is short for 阿非利加洲.

See the article "[各大洲名称由来](http://qhs.mca.gov.cn/article/llyj/dmwh/200711/20071100004830.shtml)".

Answer (score 10):

1. 亞洲 (亚洲) is short for 亞細亞洲 (亚细亚洲, Asia) which can be found as early as [坤輿萬國全圖](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E5%9D%A4%E8%BC%BF%E8%90%AC%E5%9C%8B%E5%85%A8%E5%9C%96) published in 1602 (萬曆三十年) , mainly by Italian Jesuit priest [Matteo Ricci or 利瑪竇 (Lì Mǎdòu), 6 Oct 1552 - 11 May 1610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matteo_Ricci), who is [believed](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9D%A4%E8%BC%BF%E4%B8%87%E5%9B%BD%E5%85%A8%E5%9B%B3) to coin this transliteration into Chinese characters.
2. 非洲 is from 阿非利加洲 (Africa). The above [work](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E5%9D%A4%E8%BC%BF%E8%90%AC%E5%9C%8B%E5%85%A8%E5%9C%96), however, gives a different name for Africa: 利未亞 (Libya) for some historical reason.

   利未亞 is also adopted in [海國圖志](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E6%B5%B7%E5%9B%BD%E5%9B%BE%E5%BF%97) ([影印本 in National University of Singapore](http://libapps2.nus.edu.sg/sea_chinese/doc_bg/hai%20guo%20tu%20zhi/cover%20page1.htm)), published in 1843 (道光二十三年), by [魏源](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E9%AD%8F%E6%BA%90_%28%E6%B8%85%E6%9C%9D%29), who referenced some British geographical work.

   But from [瀛寰志略](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E7%80%9B%E5%AF%B0%E5%BF%97%E7%95%A5), published in 1849 (道光二十九年), by [徐繼畬](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E5%BE%90%E7%BB%A7%E7%95%AC), we can see 阿非利加 there.